Python cryptography model wheel for iOS (arm64)
I'm trying to use cryptography Python module with the Python-Framework and PythonKit for iOS in Swift.
Since rust is needed it creates a binary (_rust.abi3.so) in bindings where I get this error:

.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D10560B-E4C2-4367-A773-1E8EB170E278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA01303A-7E6E-45A5-81FA-21834A8936AC/pythontest.app/PythonScripts/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so' (no such file), '/Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D10560B-E4C2-4367-A773-1E8EB170E278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA01303A-7E6E-45A5-81FA-21834A8936AC/pythontest.app/PythonScripts/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so' (mach-o file (/Users/kevin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D10560B-E4C2-4367-A773-1E8EB170E278/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA01303A-7E6E-45A5-81FA-21834A8936AC/pythontest.app/PythonScripts/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so), but incompatible platform (have 'macOS', need 'iOS-sim'))

Is the a working universal or arm64 wheel for the iOS-Platform?
Thank you
